# In maximum likelihood, pattern matrix, one case $>1.0$

Tags: spss, modeling, maximum-likelihood, factor-analysis

How bad is this for my model?

I've used ML (maximum likelihood) with promax rotation and Kaiser on a dataset ($n>300$) to extract underlying factors to build a model. Eigenvalue selection was reset from $.1$ to $.5$, so as to focus on cases (questions) that explain the most covariance according to underlying factors. I hope my explanation makes sense, as I`m new to this. Anyways, 9 clean factors emerged, with only this one troubling number, in the pattern matrix.

I tested reliability of the factors with ANOVA and reliability was excellent (most factors above $.900$).

I`ve already used the information to refine and collect data with a questionnaire, but this one number is still troubling me. Does it invalidate the model? Is it a serious flaw in my model? What are the implications of a case number in the pattern matrix being $>1.0$?

None of the communalities were $>1.0$, so I don`t think this is a Heywood case.

This is potentially a serious problem, as it might necessitate me redoing the model and adding a year to my studies - the questionnaire is a longitudinal one, taking one academic year. Also, I am interested in publishing the resulting questionnaire to aid in others` related research, but if this one number is a serious error, then publication is out of the question.

I would greatly appreciate some advice regarding this problem.

Comment: If you're speaking of pattern matrix loadings, they can exceed 1 under oblique rotation; pattern matrix are regression weights, not correlation coefficients.

Comment: I`d like to mark this as answered (thank you!) but I can`t find how to do that.